# Realizar tarea muy pesada en segundo plano php

Tags: php

Cargo un fichero desde mi web con php, pero la tarea puede tardar en finalizar unos 5 minutos, en principio el tamaño del fichero puede aumentar.

La cuestión es, ¿es posible realizar la tarea en segundo plano?

He visto que tanto una petición POST o GET en un formulario o una consulta Ajax depende la duración de su ejecución de la propiedad *Timeout*.

¿Existe alguna forma de realizar una tarea sin tener en cuenta el timeout?

Comment: ¿no es posible dejar esa tarea en una cola? Y después ir a mirar el estado de la cola e informar eso?
No creo que sea tan buena idea dejar pegado 5 minutos una tarea que está ocurriendo en el servidor, ya que es altamente probable que se corte por otras razones.

Comment: @rfrp no es posible, ya que no se sabe cuando se subirá los archivos.

Comment: @nachfren, lo puedes hacer a través de un llamada AJAX, con una API, o algo similar, pero vas a tener que modificar el tiempo de subida, para evitar el TimeOut, o bien, controlar el tamaño del fichero a subir.

Comment: @nachfren ¿pero tu problema es de esperar a que se suba el archivo o gatillar una tarea en cuanto se suba el archivo? En algún momento, solucione un problema similar: Necesitaba subir unas fotos (8 megas) y procesarlas (ese procesamiento tomaba unos minutos). Mientras no terminara, había un mensaje de "foto en proceso". Por el lado del servidor, había un demonio con inotify esperando a que llegaran las imagenes. inotify permite gatillar acciones a nivel de sistema en función de lo que pase en el FS (que termine de escribirse la foto por ejemplo).
¿es ese tu problema?

Comment: @rfrp eso es, creo que me puede valer inotify, le echaré un vistazo. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, por lo que sé, lo que podrías hacer seria localizar el `setTimeout` y aumentar-lo. Lo harías de la siguiente manera:

En el archivo php.ini localizar estas lineas y modificar-las:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M

max_execution_time = 60
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Añado lo que he encontrado, podrías utilizar un worker y la función sería `GearmanClient::addTaskBackground` lo harías de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

# El script del cliente

# Creamos el cliente gearman
$gmc= new GearmanClient();

# Añade el servidor de trabajos por defecto
$gmc->addServer();

# Establece un par de llamadas de retorno de modo que pueda seguirse el progreso
$gmc->setCompleteCallback("reverse_complete");
$gmc->setStatusCallback("reverse_status");

# Añade una tarea para la función "reverse"
$task= $gmc->addTask("reverse", "Hello World!", null, "1");

# Añade otra tarea, pero esta se ejecuta en segundo plano
$task= $gmc->addTaskBackground("reverse", "!dlroW olleH", null, "2");

if (! $gmc->runTasks())
{
    echo "ERROR " . $gmc->error() . "\n";
    exit;
}

echo "DONE\n";

function reverse_status($task)
{
    echo "STATUS: " . $task->unique() . ", " . $task->jobHandle() . " - " . $task->taskNumerator() . 
         "/" . $task->taskDenominator() . "\n";
}

function reverse_complete($task)
{
    echo "COMPLETE: " . $task->unique() . ", " . $task->data() . "\n";
}

?>
<?php

# El script del trabajador

echo "Starting\n";

# Creamos el objeto trabajador
$gmworker= new GearmanWorker();

# Añade el servidor por defecto (localhost)
$gmworker->addServer();

# Registra la función "reverse" en el servidor
$gmworker->addFunction("reverse", "reverse_fn");

print "Waiting for job...\n";
while($gmworker->work())
{
  if ($gmworker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
  {
    echo "return_code: " . $gmworker->returnCode() . "\n";
    break;
  }
}

function reverse_fn($job)
{
  echo "Received job: " . $job->handle() . "\n";

  $workload = $job->workload();
  $workload_size = $job->workloadSize();

  echo "Workload: $workload ($workload_size)\n";

  # Este bucle de estado no es neceasario, únicamente muestra cómo funciona
  for ($x= 0; $x < $workload_size; $x++)
  {
    echo "Sending status: " . $x + 1 . "/$workload_size complete\n";
    $job->sendStatus($x+1, $workload_size);
    $job->sendData(substr($workload, $x, 1));
    sleep(1);
  }

  $result= strrev($workload);
  echo "Result: $result\n";

  # Retorna lo que se quiere enviar al cliente
  return $result;
}

?>
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero busco si es posible ejecutar una tarea saltando el timeout. Sé que podría aumentar el tiempo pero no es la forma que busco.

Comment: Ya había visto esta función, la probaré mañana.

Answer (score 0):

Para establecer o quitar el limite de tiempo de un script PHP es necesario agregar lo siguiente al inicio del archivo:

```
// 300 segundos -> 5 minutos
ini_set( 'max_execution_time' , 300 );
// 0 -> Quita el limite de tiempo
ini_set( 'max_execution_time' , 0 );
```

Tambien si la tarea lo permite, puede usar un script de tipo CRON para que realice esa tarea cada cierto tiempo en paralelo a la ejecución de la aplicación.

Comment: al igual que le he dicho al compañero, no quiero aumentar el tiempo, gracias!